# Discord.py how to tell if a player has sent a message, of any type

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a exp system, and to do that, I need to see if a user sends any message, so, how would I check that in discord.py?

Comment: discord.py should use magic.c

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about your requirement?  Are you rtying to do something whenever a member sends a message, or are you chacking to see is that person has sent a message?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) you can do something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    print("{} user has sent a message in {}".format(msg.author.name,msg.channel.name))
    #whatever you want to do with the XP system
```